# PHP: How to POST value of an input which contains [] in the name attribute?

Tags: php

I swear i couldn't find a simple working solution for this.

On a form i have inputs that have names containing "[]" and i cant change the names of the inputs because they are part of a script.

I want to php POST the values of those inputs at the next page, after the form submit.

Example of input

```
<input type="text" name="CustomFields[13]" id="CustomFields_13_1" value="">
```

Anyone knows how to accomplish it?

I want to do it using PHP only

Comment: The question is not clear at all

Comment: What problem are you having? PHP should be getting those values as an array

Comment: **Use `vardump($_POST)`**. Debugging this is *extremely* trivial and you need to learn to help yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name is `CustomFields[13]`, then you can access it at `$_POST['CustomFields']['13']`.

Answer (score 0):

You "cannot" POST something with PHP. It's always the client that POSTs to the server. PHP is running on server side.

I recommend that you use sessions and save there the values that you need to have available in next pages.

This is how you set a session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['CustomField'] = "test";
```

And this is how you get it:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['CustomField']; //Should display "test"
```

Comment: there are many "CustomField" what i need is to save it to later post the values, how would u do it with a session if u have many inputs like CustomField[13] CustomField[14] on and on